# Nested 'synchronize': How can this synchronized Java method be refactored - and could it make any sense like this?

Tags: java, concurrency, refactoring, synchronized

I stumbled across this method in a project i am working on, and immediately thought that something is wrong. I had the feeling this can't be any proper idom for anything.

But i don't get the intentions and implications of this. Can this be refactored? Does the second synchronized make any sense - and isn't the third synchronized redundant/unnecessary?

I am just starting to get into advanced concurrent/threadsafe programming in java - a detailed explanation why this makes sense or no sense  and why is much appreciated!

```
 @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        synchronized (this.market) {
            synchronized (this.market.getWallet()) {
                this.handler.handleEvent(new WalletLecherEvent(this, market,
                        market.leechWallet()));
            }
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance

edit, in order to supply more context:

```
public class WalletLeecherWorker extends Worker {
        private IAbstractMarketAPI market = null;

        private Thread thread = null;

        public WalletLeecherWorker(IEventHandler handler, IAbstractMarketAPI market) {
            super(handler);
            this.market = market;
        }

        public void startThread() {
            if (thread != null)
                return;

            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }

        public MARKETs getMarket() {
            return this.market.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            synchronized (this.market) {
                synchronized (this.market.getWallet()) {
                    this.handler.handleEvent(new WalletLecherEvent(this, market,
                            market.leechWallet()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

..and the method `market.getWallet()`:

```
@Override
public Wallet getWallet() {
    return this.wallet;
}
```

I *think* that the intention is to block all threads from getting *old* Wallets, thus wrongfully synchronized/ deprecated data - as long as this thread runs();

Comment: None of your questions are answerable without more context. It depends on who else has access to these values and in what ways.

Comment: I understand @shmosel but doesn't this highly raise your suspicion? 
The second synchronized synchronizes access to this.market - the following code synchronizes access to a method of the same object - isn't this redundant?

I'll add some more context..

Comment: Suspicious? Yes. Wrong? I can't say.

Comment: So for it seems pretty reasonable. The first `synchronized` could be necessary in case a worker is started twice (either through `startThread()` or through `run()`). The second one could be to protect a market shared between workers. The third one could be to protect a wallet shared between markets. I'm not saying those are all necessarily possible, but the context is still limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code obtains the locks on the following objects:

- `this` - Prevents multiple threads from calling `run()` on the same `WalletLeecherWorker` instance
- `this.market` - Prevents the `run()` from proceeding if another thread has obtained a lock on it, which is a reasonable assumption considering that the `market` instance is probably shared
- `this.market.wallet` - Same as previous

None of these are obviously unnecessary, except for the `run()` method being synchronized. It offers no protection beyond what the following synchronized block does. The code itself could be because of very fine grained locking being used, with this particular code needing to lock everything, whereas other code may lock only the wallet or the market and the wallet.

However this code can be error (and even deadlock) prone. If you lock the objects in the wrong order, you can get a deadlock. It's also not very readable as you see. It's also dubious to have a `Thread` as an instance variable of the class with a `startThread()` method. The code may not be broken, but it's certainly not very pretty.

Comment: There could theoretically be a method in there that replaces `market`, making the outer synchronization still necessary.

Comment: very nice explanation. Indeed the market-Instance is shared. So ..the 'synchronized' in front of run() is likely to be redundant?

Comment: @shmosel In theory yes, but I doubt it. This code looks like a less-than-optimally implemented asynchronous task. The kind that if written with current tools you'd use an `Executor` and better concurrency primitives, so you wouldn't have any `synchronized` blocks in the code.

Comment: @Gewure Well based on the code it doesn't do anything that isn't achieved by the following synchronized block, but I wouldn't remove it just for fun, since that's just a drop in the ocean.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for the hint to Executor. With concurrency primitives you mean the Atomics i think?
Generally spoken, there should be unique access points for synchronized data which don't stretch across many classes, am i right?

Comment: @Gewure I mean any and all of the `java.util.concurrent.*` classes. `synchronized` is often a mark of older code, since there are now a lot better, easier and more performant tools for writing concurrent code.